# Ordering data based on two variables but with a cut-off point

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am able to construct a new data frame based on the data below where each row comprises the expectation values of each categorical variable in the ID column, taken in ascending order of time. But how can I do this up until a cut off point in time. For example, if I only want values to be taken in chronological order until time = 5.

```
library('dplyr')
library('purrr')
df <- read.csv("data.csv", header = TRUE)
# df
      ID Time Expectation
1  NJL.1    3         0.1
2  NJL.1    1         0.1
3  NJL.1    2         0.1
4  NJL.1    4         0.1
5  NJL.1    6         0.1
6  NJL.1    5       100.0
7  NJL.1   10         0.1
8  NJL.1    8         0.1
9  NJL.1    9         0.1
10 NJL.1    7         0.1
11 NJL.2   10         0.1
12 NJL.2    1         0.1
13 NJL.2    3         0.1
14 NJL.2    6         0.1
15 NJL.2    4         0.1
16 NJL.2    2         6.0
17 NJL.2    5         0.1
18 NJL.2    8         7.0
19 NJL.2    9         8.0
20 NJL.2    7         0.1
21 NJL.3    3         0.1
22 NJL.3    1         0.1
23 NJL.3    2         0.1
24 NJL.3    4         0.1
25 NJL.3    6         0.1
26 NJL.3    5        10.0
27 NJL.3   10         0.1
28 NJL.3    8         0.1
29 NJL.3    9         0.1
30 NJL.3    7         0.1

df <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(var = list(Expectation[order(Time)]), 
            var_ts = purrr::map(var, ts))
```

So for example, for NJL.1, values would be (0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1. 100) and all other expectation values are ignored.

Many thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing! I'm a newbie :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a `data.table` approach

**sample data**

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
#or
df <- fread("row ID Time Expectation
1  NJL.1    3         0.1
2  NJL.1    1         0.1
3  NJL.1    2         0.1
4  NJL.1    4         0.1
5  NJL.1    6         0.1
6  NJL.1    5       100.0
7  NJL.1   10         0.1
8  NJL.1    8         0.1
9  NJL.1    9         0.1
10 NJL.1    7         0.1
11 NJL.2   10         0.1
12 NJL.2    1         0.1
13 NJL.2    3         0.1
14 NJL.2    6         0.1
15 NJL.2    4         0.1
16 NJL.2    2         6.0
17 NJL.2    5         0.1
18 NJL.2    8         7.0
19 NJL.2    9         8.0
20 NJL.2    7         0.1
21 NJL.3    3         0.1
22 NJL.3    1         0.1
23 NJL.3    2         0.1
24 NJL.3    4         0.1
25 NJL.3    6         0.1
26 NJL.3    5        10.0
27 NJL.3   10         0.1
28 NJL.3    8         0.1
29 NJL.3    9         0.1
30 NJL.3    7         0.1")
```

**code**

```
#set keys for sorting
setkey( df, ID, Time )

#filter values by group
ans <- df[ df[, .I[Time <= 5], by = ID]$V1 ]
#    row    ID Time Expectation
# 1:   2 NJL.1    1         0.1
# 2:   3 NJL.1    2         0.1
# 3:   1 NJL.1    3         0.1
# 4:   4 NJL.1    4         0.1
# 5:   6 NJL.1    5       100.0
# 6:  12 NJL.2    1         0.1
# 7:  16 NJL.2    2         6.0
# 8:  13 NJL.2    3         0.1
# 9:  15 NJL.2    4         0.1
# 10: 17 NJL.2    5         0.1
# 11: 22 NJL.3    1         0.1
# 12: 23 NJL.3    2         0.1
# 13: 21 NJL.3    3         0.1
# 14: 24 NJL.3    4         0.1
# 15: 26 NJL.3    5        10.0
```

Now you can easily summarise, paste+collapse, dcast, etc.. to get desired output.

Examples:

```
ans[, .(values = paste0( Expectation, collapse = "," ) ), by = ID ]
#       ID              values
# 1: NJL.1 0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,100
# 2: NJL.2   0.1,6,0.1,0.1,0.1
# 3: NJL.3  0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,10
```

or

```
dcast(ans, ID ~ Time, value.var = "Expectation")
#       ID   1   2   3   4     5
# 1: NJL.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 100.0
# 2: NJL.2 0.1 6.0 0.1 0.1   0.1
# 3: NJL.3 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1  10.0
```

Comment: Thanks @Wimpel! What if I wanted only the expectation values between time = 2 and time = 5?

Comment: It's OK I have the answer for this now :-)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you indeed want the `Time`s ordered as asked, in base R you can do

```
dat <- with(dat, {dat <- dat[Time <= 5, ];dat[order(ID, Time), ]})
dat
#       ID Time Expectation
# 2  NJL.1    1         0.1
# 3  NJL.1    2         0.1
# 1  NJL.1    3         0.1
# 4  NJL.1    4         0.1
# 6  NJL.1    5       100.0
# 12 NJL.2    1         0.1
# 16 NJL.2    2         6.0
# 13 NJL.2    3         0.1
# 15 NJL.2    4         0.1
# 17 NJL.2    5         0.1
# 22 NJL.3    1         0.1
# 23 NJL.3    2         0.1
# 21 NJL.3    3         0.1
# 24 NJL.3    4         0.1
# 26 NJL.3    5        10.0
```

---

*Data*

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = c("NJL.1", "NJL.1", "NJL.1", "NJL.1", "NJL.1", 
"NJL.1", "NJL.1", "NJL.1", "NJL.1", "NJL.1", "NJL.2", "NJL.2", 
"NJL.2", "NJL.2", "NJL.2", "NJL.2", "NJL.2", "NJL.2", "NJL.2", 
"NJL.2", "NJL.3", "NJL.3", "NJL.3", "NJL.3", "NJL.3", "NJL.3", 
"NJL.3", "NJL.3", "NJL.3", "NJL.3"), Time = c(3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
6L, 5L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 
7L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 7L), Expectation = c(0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 100, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 6, 0.1, 7, 8, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 10, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

This subsets your `df`to the desired values:

```
df[which(df$Time <= 5),]    

        row    ID Time Expectation
 1:   1 NJL.1    3         0.1
 2:   2 NJL.1    1         0.1
 3:   3 NJL.1    2         0.1
 4:   4 NJL.1    4         0.1
 5:   6 NJL.1    5       100.0
 6:  12 NJL.2    1         0.1
 7:  13 NJL.2    3         0.1
 8:  15 NJL.2    4         0.1
 9:  16 NJL.2    2         6.0
10:  17 NJL.2    5         0.1
11:  21 NJL.3    3         0.1
12:  22 NJL.3    1         0.1
13:  23 NJL.3    2         0.1
14:  24 NJL.3    4         0.1
15:  26 NJL.3    5        10.0
```

To order the dataframe, first save it, say, as `dfnew`:

```
dfnew <- df[df$Time <= 3 & df$Time <= 5,]
```

Then simply use `order` thus:

```
dfnew[order(ID, Time), ]

   row    ID Time Expectation
1:   2 NJL.1    1         0.1
2:   3 NJL.1    2         0.1
3:   1 NJL.1    3         0.1
4:  12 NJL.2    1         0.1
5:  16 NJL.2    2         6.0
6:  13 NJL.2    3         0.1
7:  22 NJL.3    1         0.1
8:  23 NJL.3    2         0.1
9:  21 NJL.3    3         0.1
```

Comment: Oh thanks! How would the code change if I wanted to subset between time = 3 and time = 5?

Comment: That would be `df[which(df$Time <= 3 & df$Time <= 5),]`. Works just as well without `which`: `df[df$Time <= 3 & df$Time <= 5,]`